# How to inner join in pandas as SQL , Stuck in a problem below

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have two df named "df" and second as "topwud".

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65xm3.png)

[topwud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYLSH.png)

when I join these two dataframes bt inner join using BOMCPNO and PRTNO as the join column

like

```
second_level=pd.merge(df,top_wud ,left_on='BOMCPNO', right_on='PRTNO', how='inner').drop_duplicates()
```

Then I got this data frame

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeDuo.png)

I don't want common name coming as PRTNO_x and PRTNO_y , I want to keep only PRTNO_x in my result dataframe as name "PRTNO" which is default name.
Kindly help me :)

Comment: Why dont you just drop the column and rename the one you want to after result is generated? just put it as a part of process

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: How about you set BOMCPNO as index of df and PRTNO as index of top_wud and then perform merge on left and right indexes, 
pd.merge(df.set_index('BOMCPNO'),top_wud.set_index('PRTNO'), left_index=True, right_index=True)?

Answer (score 1):

try This -

```
pd.merge(df1, top_wud, on=['BOMCPNO', 'PRTNO'])
```

What this will do though is return only the values where BOMCPNO and PRTNO exist in both dataframes as the default merge type is an inner merge.

So what you could do is compare this merged df size with your first one and see if they are the same and if so you could do a merge on both columns or just drop/rename the _x/_y suffix B columns.

I would spend time though determining if these values are indeed the same and exist in both dataframes, in which case you may wish to perform an outer merge:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'], how='outer')
```

Then what you could do is then drop duplicate rows (and possibly any NaN rows) and that should give you a clean merged dataframe.

```
merged_df.drop_duplicates(cols=['BOMCPNO', 'PRTNO'],inplace=True)
```

also try other types of join , as i dont know what exactly you want, i think its left inner .

check this if it solved your problem.